# Suggestion of UML diagram

Tags: android, uml, class-diagram, use-case

I need to draw a diagram but I am not sure what sort of diagram that is appropriate for my application.

It is a mobile application that contains:

1. Splash (as welcoming scree)
2. Main Menu Screen (Which contains)

   - Gallery
   - Settings
   - Map
   - Help

The Gallery has contain all the images/photos that is stored on the device.

Can anyone suggest what sort of UML that is appropriate for this application? Is it Use Case Diagram? or Sequence Diagram?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose for the diagram?  The different diagrams show different information, so some sort of context is needed to help answer this question.

Comment: I want to describe the development in diagram but I'm not sure about it; As Im developing a mobile application I need some sort of diagram to represent it.

Does Eclipse provide this kind of tool to generate the diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you should be clear about what you're trying to achieve before generating documentation, otherwise you can end up with heaps of useless charts and diagrams.

If I were you, I'd use a Class Diagram with a Use Case diagram.

The Class Diagram will help you and other technically-minded people to understand how your code fits together.

Then use a Use Case Diagram to show the flow of typical use of your program. This should be understandable by anyone.

Comment: Thanks for the info; I was wondering if Eclipse able to generate class diagram and Use Case diagram for you?

Comment: Not that I know of. There are UML tools that will do that for you but Eclipse isn't one of them (as far as I know). Also, I'm not sure if you can get UML tools to generate anything smarter than a class diagram from code.

Comment: Thanks Mike, so are you saying that I could generate class diagram from the code that I implemented using Eclipse? If so, can you please suggest any and How? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the slow reply. Yes you can do that. There are free tools you can use to do it for you. There are a number of tools listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120032/what-is-your-favorite-automatic-class-diagram-generator-for-eclipse

Comment: Thanksa again, I have created a use case diagram here is the link:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/401/ucdiagram00.png/

and create a activity diagram 

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/857/activitydiagram.png/

But my activity diagram isn't the correct format; can you suggest me how can I make it to the right format?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe you can try adjust settings in the tool you used or try another tool?

Answer (score 1):

Hi every application/project requires activity diagram for its final implementation besides usecase,sequence,statechart.Heres the link hope this will help you
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_activity_diagram.htm